# How to intercept websocket connections electron

Tags: websocket, electron

I'm able to intercept any website WebSocket connection and handle incoming messages and send messages from my userscripts (using violentmonkey) code:

my old userscripts from violentmonkey/tampermonkey

```
    var SocketConnection
    window.WebSocket = function (...args) {
      const socket = new nativeWebSocket(...args);
      SocketConnection = socket
      SocketConnection.addEventListener('message', (event) => { console.log(event) });
      SocketConnection.addEventListener('open', (event) => { console.log(event)})
      return socket;
    }
```

this script makes the `SocketConnection` usable in all the other parts of the scripts without interrupting the original website websocket connection (I still can see the messages thru the Developer Console -> Network -> WS) and in my message function can handle and send another message using the `SocketConnection` object.

I'm trying to port this script to Electron (with typescript), but without success, the connection is visible in the Developer Console -> Network -> WS, but not in the code below

```
const nativeWebSocket = window.WebSocket;

var SocketInterceptor: WebSocket;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // <---- WORKS
  console.log("Hi i'm working")
  console.log(window.WebSocket)
  console.log(SocketInterceptor) 
});

(window as any).WebSocket = (...args:any) => { // <---- DO NOT WORK
  alert("Called")
  const socket = new nativeWebSocket(args);
  SocketInterceptor = socket
  SocketInterceptor.addEventListener('message', (event:any) => {
    alert("Message ")
    console.log("MESSAGE")
  });
  SocketInterceptor.addEventListener('open', (event:any) => {
    alert("Opened")
    console.log("SOCKET OPENED")
  })   
  return socket;
}
```

the part of the DOMContentLoaded works good, but the .WebSocket override of the native new WebSocket function doesn't (nothing happens, no message at the console neither in the alert), I guess it's never called by the website (besides I can print the window.WebSocket after the injection and see that the native WebSocket was updated with my code)

I'm missing something that should be different in Electron?

Answer (score 2):

I found why it's not working: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation

TLDR: `Main` vs `Renderer` -> The window object is isolated from the real window object that normally we manipulate thru userscripts, so the website was calling new WebSocket from the window that has the scope (renderer) of the website, the window that I have modified (main) was never called (I guess thats the short explanation)

Read the link above with much more details about it

I choose the path of removing the contextIsolation (read about it in the link above)

```
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
```

now I can intercept the socket messages like I was doing before.

For me and since that I'm the only one that will use it, it's really enough.

Thanks